# Evaluate the improper integral $\int_0^\infty {\exp(−sk)\over k}\sin(kx)\,dk$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty {\exp(−sk)\over k}\sin(kx)\,dk$$

I've tried hard for this but of no use.I've applied integration by parts by which I get $$\int_0^\infty \exp(-sk)\sin(kx)\,dk=\frac{x}{x^2+ s^2}.$$ But, I'm not getting how to adjust $\displaystyle\frac1k$.

Please Help!

Comment: You need elliptic functions to do your integral. Are you sure you copied the problem correctly? Was this integral derived from something?

Comment: @Christopher Carl Heckman:Thanks,Will you please tell me how to make the sign of definite integral.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman:actually,I got a problem to find the inverse sine transformation of exp(-sk)/k

Comment: Do you mean inverse *hyperbolic* sine transformation, by any chance?

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman:NO,its ordinary sine function with argument (k*x)

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman:Sorry! its Inverse fourier sine transformation.

Comment: That's a new one for me. The answer is at http://dlmf.nist.gov/1.14#vii , but they don't say how they got it. ... This question was also answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878788/fourier-sine-transform-of-frac1x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39006/discussion-between-pk-styles-and-christopher-carl-heckman).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We assume $x>0$ and $s>0$.

Then by differentiating the following identity with respect to $s$,
$$
f(s)=\int_0^\infty {\exp(−sk)\over k}\sin(kx)\,dk
$$ one may write
$$
f'(s)=-\int_0^\infty \exp(−sk)\sin(kx)\,dk=-\frac{x}{x^2+ s^2}
$$ giving
$$
f(s)=-\arctan \left( \frac{s}x\right)+C.
$$ Observing that, as $s \to \infty$, $f(s) \to 0$, we then obtain $C=\dfrac\pi2$. Thus

> $$
> \int_0^\infty {\exp(−sk)\over k}\sin(kx)\,dk=\frac\pi2-\arctan \left( \frac{s}x\right), \qquad s>0,\,x>0.
> $$

Comment: :I'm not gettnig why you've assumed x>0 and s>0.How will the question get affected if we ignore these assumptions.Thank you!!

Comment: For $s\leq0$ your initial integral does *not* exist. the case $x>0$ is just to avoid handling absolute value. Thanks.

Comment: :Thanks,I got it.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: :Will you please tell me how to make the definite integral sign.I've already checked the MathsJax tutorial.

Comment: \int_a^b f(x)\,dx

Answer (score 0):

@ChristopherCarlHeckman : it is a **Laplace Transform** (see remark at the end)

Precisely, it is the Laplace Transform (LT) of a very important function, the **cardinal sine** (sinc).

This LT can be found in most LT tables as

$$\int_0^\infty {\sin(k)\over k}\exp(−sk)\,dk=\frac\pi2-\arctan(s)$$

from which it is easy to deduce by an elementary change of variables:

$$\int_0^\infty {\sin(kx)\over k}\exp(−sk)\,dk=\frac\pi2-\arctan \left( \frac{s}x\right)$$

Remark 1: This result can also be written $arccot\left( \frac{s}x\right)$.

Remark 2: In the reference dlmf.nist.gov/1.14#vii  given by ChristopherCarlHeckman the result they give is not the same... I don't understand.

Comment: I knew that it was related to a Laplace Transform. I just hadn't worked with it before.

Comment: Not only to Laplace Transform but to the cardinal sine, two points that no other colleague had underlined.